# Test fails in tests.py but succeeds in python shell

Tags: django-testing

I'm a newbee to python and django and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a Site object:

```
class Site (models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    support_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices= SITE_SUPPORTED_STATUS, blank=False)
    requests = models.IntegerField()
    objects = SiteManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.domain, self.support_status)
```

And a SiteManager object

```
class SiteManager(models.Manager):
    def supported_site_counts(self):
        i = self.filter(support_status__iexact="SUPPORTED").count()
        return i
```

From the console, the method "supported_site_counts()" works just fine

```
>>(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from bookmark.models import Site, SiteManager
>>> Site.objects.supported_site_counts()
>>>>2012-05-18 18:09:20,027 DEBUG (0.001) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bookmark_site" WHERE
>>>>"bookmark_site"."support_status" LIKE SUPPORTED ESCAPE '\' ; args=(u'SUPPORTED',)
>>>>2012-05-18 18:09:20,028 DEBUG Got 1 supported site
>>>>1
```

But when it's called from a testcase, the count returns as 0

```
class SiteManagerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_supported_site_counts(self):
        self.x = False
        self.count = Site.objects.supported_site_counts()
        logging.debug(self.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the tests will set up a database separate from your development database to run the tests in.  You will need to put testing data in to the testing database, either programmatically or using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#django.test.TestCase.fixtures).